# Taking a picture and passing it to a different UIViewController Swift 3.0

Tags: swift, image, uiimageview, uiimage

I'm trying to take an image in my app so I can save it to my device and pass it to the next view controller to be previewed.  The way I see people doing this is storing the image they take in a uiimage.  Then during prepareforsegue they set the uiimage variable in the destination view controller to the photo you took in the previous view controller.  From there in the dest view controller I see people displaying the image as follows : imageName.image = imageVariable .  When I pass the variable to the destination view controller and try to display it in the next view controller it appears as a nil value.  Where am I going wrong?

First ViewController:

```
 override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "ToDetailPage" {
        let nextScene = segue.destination as! PostDetailPageViewController
        nextScene.itemImage = self.image
       // nextScene?.myimg.image = self.image
    }
}

@IBAction func TakePhotoButtonClicked(_ sender: AnyObject) {

    if let videoConnection = sessionOutput.connection(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo){

        sessionOutput.captureStillImageAsynchronously(from: videoConnection, completionHandler: {
        buffer, error in
            let imageData = AVCaptureStillImageOutput.jpegStillImageNSDataRepresentation(buffer)
            self.image = UIImage(data: imageData!)
            UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(UIImage(data: imageData!)!, nil, nil, nil)
        })

    }


}
```

Second ViewController:

```
 var itemImage: UIImage!
@IBOutlet weak var myimg: UIImageView!

override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.categories.dataSource = self;
    self.categories.delegate = self;
    setUpMap()
    myimg.image = itemImage

}
```

Comment: Is `self.image` nonnil in `prepare(for segue:)`?

Comment: @Ryan ok yea that would explain why its not passing any value.  Its nil in prepareforsegue! Any ideas why its not storing the image in the takephotobuttonclicked method?

Comment: What about in `sessionOutput.captureStillImageAsynchronously` block? Was there any error? `self.image` in the block is non nil?

Comment: have you check if self.image is non nil ?

Comment: @Ryan there is no errors in the block but it isnt setting the image here for some reason             self.image = UIImage(data: imageData!)
Could this be because the image is still saving?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to push viewController inside the block. Actually what is happening in this code the completion block is called after prepareForSegue. So your image is always 'nil'.

Try to push the viewController like this:

```
if let videoConnection = sessionOutput.connection(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo){


sessionOutput.captureStillImageAsynchronously(from: videoConnection, completionHandler: {
        buffer, error in
            let imageData = AVCaptureStillImageOutput.jpegStillImageNSDataRepresentation(buffer)
            self.image = UIImage(data: imageData!)
            UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(UIImage(data: imageData!)!, nil, nil, nil)
// push view controller here
let destinationVC = SecondViewController()
destinationVC.image = self.image
self.navigationController.pushViewController(destinationVC, animated: true)
        })
 }
```

Hope it will help you.. Happy Coding!!

Comment: Thank you so much @iProgrammer !  I had to make a few changes to my code because of a nil value with the destinationVC but it works !  I appreciate your time.